# Websphere wsadmin read csv

Tags: java, websphere, jython, websphere-7

Is it possible to make Websphere to work with CSV? I would love to leverage jython csv module. But it seems default Websphere 7 jython doesn't have that.

Is it possible to either include a jar in the classpath or upgrade the jython in websphere

Please advise

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to extract Lib/csv.py from the latest [jython distribution](http://www.jython.org/downloads.html) and place it into WAS_ROOT/optionalLibraries/jython/Lib.

Let us know if that worked :)

Comment: Getting exception when importing the csv, looks like I have to upgrade the whole jython env. then just one .py?
File "C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\optionalLibraries\jython\Lib\csv.py", line 7, in ?
ImportError: no module named _csv

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced the whole jython installation in the websphere with the new jython 2.5.2 (simple copy and paste) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

IBM have some detailed instructions on how to upgrade websphere to jython 2.5

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1207_vansickel/1207_vansickel.html